# Was there any notable pushback against "dark" (lack of lighting) cinematography?

Tags: film-techniques, cinematography, reception, lighting

One of the most common "normal people" gripes I usually hear about TV shows and films is that directors love to shoot "dark" scenes (literally dark - there is not enough lighting to be able to see almost anything), which is absolutely detrimental in enjoying an action scene.

Has there ever been notable pushback against this cinematographic approach, either by mass viewers, or notable critics, or industry professionals?

Comment: While an interesting question, I see a little problem with the disparity between "normal people" and mass viewers here. On the one hand you hear enough notable pushback about this to consider this question and on the other hand you ask for more notable pushback. The phrasing might deserve some improvement.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson - i mean, I hear tons of people griping - enough to know it's a "thing", but it's all individual complaints. The "mass viewers" means some sort of organized thing - e.g. a poll/survey indicating general opposition to the approach, or petition, or just clearly-demonstrable public complaints that can be measured e.g. on rotten tomatoes

Comment: In part, shooting darker is itself probably a pushback against the even, flat lighting that's also common, esp. on tv. So it's pushback on pushback on pushback as with so many things. But another trend is also more frenetic action scenes with freely moving cameras (the _Bourne_ movies did this, Michael Bay made it worse); that probably also carries some of the blame for actions scenes being harder to follow, not just the lighting.

Comment: This seems related to [this question](http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/2978/why-are-3d-films-so-dark).

Comment: "Pushback" in what sense? Criticism, boycotting, complaints sent to directors, exaggerating light in new productions?

Comment: @Joachim - any/all of the above. Plus critics' "official opinion", or articles in trade publications, or research etc...